# Check if checkbox has a class and is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm handling a checkbox.

```
if ($(this).hasClass("select")) { // To check class name
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) { // to check whether it is checked
    // some code
  }
}
```

Now I have two if statements. How to merge them in a single condition?

I've tried:

1)

```
if ($(this).hasClass("select").is(':checked')) {
  //statements
}
```

It gave me an error: `.hasClass("...").is('...') is not a function`.

2)

```
if ($(this).hasClass("select") && $(this).is(':checked')) {
  // some code
}
else if ($(this).hasClass("select") && $(this).not(':checked')) {
  // some code
}
```

It's working.

How to merge these two in single statement in a simplified manner? Can we simplify the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by,

```
var cond = $(this).is(".select:checked");
var val = parseInt($(this).parent().next().text());
sum += (cond ? val : -(val));
```

Comment: Addition is not happening

Comment: @Prabs Can u reproduce the issue in a fiddle? This should work.

Comment: Substract on uncheck of select class checkbox should happen. but this condition fails if some other class checkbox is unchecked

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sr6gaL37/3/  we have to do something similar to `var cond = $(this).is(".select"+".not(':checked')");` to substract

Answer (score 0):

You can move the class checking into `.is()`:

```
if ($(this).is(".select:checked"))
```

`$(this).hasClass("select").is(':checked')` doesn't work because `.hasClass()` returns boolean, not the `$(this)` object, so you can't chain jQuery methods on it.